# How to check a type of item in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net

Need to find out the type of an element inside a listBox, whether the type is button or radio button or simple string.

Something lie the snippet below:

```
foreach (ListBoxItem _item in listPhotoAlbum.ItemsSource)
                    {
                        if _item is of type of button 
                            //DO this
                        else if _item is  typeof RadioButton
                            //Do that
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
foreach (var _item in listPhotoAlbum.Items)
{
    var radioButton = _item as RadioButton;

    if (radioButton != null)
    {
        //Do with radioButton
        continue;
    }

    var button = _item as Button;

    if (button != null)
    {
        //Do with button
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

```
if( item is Button )
{
  // Do something
}
else if( item is RadioButton )
{
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check the type use the **is** keyword like the other questions suggest.

If you actually want to use the item as that type, then often it is better to use the **as** keyword. This does the check but gives you the actual item after the cast for use, and will prevent fxcop warnings that you would recieve if you use **is** then **as**.

```
foreach (ListBoxItem _item in listPhotoAlbum.ItemsSource)
{
    Button b = _item as Button;
    if (b != null) { // DO this }

    RadioButton rb = _item as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null) { // DO that }
}
```

If for example you wanted to know the type regardless of what is (rather than limiting to certain controls) you could then use the **GetType()** method.

```
foreach (ListBoxItem _item in listPhotoAlbum.ItemsSource)
{
    Type t = _item.GetType();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `is`?

```
foreach (ListBoxItem _item in listPhotoAlbum.ItemsSource) 
{ 
    if _item is Button  
        //DO this 
    else if _item is RadioButton 
        //Do that 
}
```